# how to get the details on each step in tests?

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports

i want to add to each and every step at the extent report (4), the details on it so i won't get it empty like [image: now,]
my code have an extent class and an ITestListener (TestNG) so the class looks like that (below)
and where it written Test pass, these is the details for now, and i want something like that [image: these]

````
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        create_test(result.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("The success test name is: "+result.getTestName());
        test.log(test.getStatus(), "Test pass");
        try {
            test.pass(result.getTestName(),MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(CaptureScreen()).build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("The failed test name is: "+result.getName());

        try {
            test.fail(result.getTestName(), MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(CaptureScreen()).build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        init();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        extent.flush();

    } ```

and test looks like :

@Test (priority = 1 ,groups= "OpenWebSite-test")
    public void upFooterOpenWebSite() {
        MapsPage.getWebSite(siteURL);
    }
````

Comment: What attempts have you made to do this? Sure, you've given us code, but how does this relate to creating a gui like that?

Comment: @FailingCoder my gui is the first picture, i want the details like the second one,
also the attempts are up there if you read it...

Comment: What do you mean you want details? What details? `how does this relate to creating a gui like that?`

Comment: the details tab is by default empty, i want it to be full with the steps, now the test pass is from ```test.log(test.getStatus(), "Test pass");``` but i want instead of these, the full steps

Comment: What do you mean by `full with the steps`? `but i want instead of these, the full steps` what full steps are there? I don't understand what you are asking. @nuzo

Comment: i guess it will be the log of the steps , or what it was taken to get to the assertion

Comment: There would be multiple ways to achieve this. With the limited details of your question, not only is it unclear, but virtually impossible to give a perfect answer; there's likely hundreds or thousands, even. Consider how users on stack overflow may answer this. Look at our six previous comments; they are all present due to miscommunication and misunderstanding.

Comment: @FailingCoder look the below answer...he understands it pretty fast without downvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `test.log(Status.INFO,"login using a valid IsoMetrix username and password");` basically you have to add `Status.INFO`of each steps and it will be available in the report.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was good unless it looks like that Extent report don't know in version 4 about LogStatus.INFO 
also, is there possible to use it with ITestListener so it will work on all tests?

Comment: yes you are right, thank you. there is option to use these in ITestListener so it will take from each step the logging instead of doing that manualy in each step?

Comment: Are you having same steps in all the testcases?

Comment: no, that's the problem if i want it, but maybe there is something at the listener that can take from each step the step and add it to the info and than to add it to the listener so i won't need to make it manually each and every step?

Comment: I have no idea about how to do it.

Comment: how would you configure it out that each test is test is looking like [these](https://imgur.com/gcfXL9I) and the methods are actually in another package and are basicly extends the basic methods?

Comment: I didn't got what you are asking. Are saying you wanna show which methods you are using and is in which package it is in, in the report?

Comment: i guess it will be better to say in which method than in which test ,so yes, methods

Comment: @Parik if the method looks like these 
 `@Test (priority = 1 ,groups= "OpenWebSite-test", testName="open web site")
 public void upFooterOpenWebSite() {
  MapsPage.getWebSite(siteURL); `
there is possible to add as step the test name? or the test name is something that comes from the testNG.XML file only?